# Lucene 7 is not consistent with Lucene 6 regarding adding TextField(field, TokenStream) to a document

Tags: java, lucene, migration

I'm adding a field to a document using TextField with TokenStream, using the following code:

```
TokenFilter contentFilter = createContentFilter(body);
Field contentField = new TextField("fieldName", contentFilter);
doc.add(contentField);
```

It used to work great with Lucene 6. However, moving to Lucene 7 I get an error message while adding the document to the index:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: startOffset must be non-negative, and endOffset must be >= startOffset, and offsets must not go backwards startOffset=0,endOffset=39,lastStartOffset=36 for field 'content'
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:767)
at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:430)
```

What ha been changed in Lucene 7 that breaks my code?
Thans, David

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is that in Lucene 7, token offsets should follow new regulations that have not been demanded before. The start offset of a token must be larger or equal than the end offset of its previous tokens. This disallow using the token's offset attribute for representing a span within the text. This is sad, very sad :)